# why my code get the result for average isn't seem correct?

Tags: python

```
import random
f = open('yearlystep.txt','w')          #write random steps for one year
for y in range(366):
    x = random.randint(0,1000)
    f.write(str(x)+'\n')

f.close()

f = open('yearlystep.txt','r')          #calculate average steps per 30 days

total = 0
for x in range(12):
    for y in range(30):
        r = f.readline()
        total += int(r)
        avg = total/30
        total = 0
    
    print(avg)

f.close()
```

unexpected output:

[image]

as you can see, i am try to write a program to calculate the average of random steps per 30 days. but its didn't get the correct result as one of the average is showing 1.0? i don't know what happened and there may be somethings wrong with my logic and code. can anyone explain with the code and describe what did i do wrong for me? thanks.

Comment: You're not writing any newlines when you create the file.

Comment: `avg = total/30` and `total = 0` are in the inner loop where they should be in the outer loop, you need to fix their indentation

Comment: The line where you compute `avg = total / 30` and then `total = 0` are at the wrong level of indentation. Right now you do that every step of the loop, but it should only be after the inner loop!

Comment: when you `print(avg)` you're printing the value of the last day of the "month" divided by 30. Why do you think that might be? By the way, did you notice that you aren't writing and reading the same number of days?

Comment: You should put `total = 0` at the beginning of the month loop, so you don't need to repeat it at the end of the loop.

Comment: @Nick thank you, solved perfectly! can you also post as answer so i can close the question?

Comment: @Ruzihm i don't understand? can you try to explain with my code so its better for understanding?

Comment: @MINO step through your code with a pencil and paper and it will help you understand why the printed numbers had nothing to do with the first 29 numbers of each month. You will have a more helpful learning experience if you learn that skill instead of having it explained to you. And this is python, so be sure to pay very close attention to indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have incorrectly indented these two lines:

```
avg = total/30
total = 0
```

which has placed them into your inner loop when they should be in the outer one. Correcting that should give the correct results. As @Barmar points out, you can move the assignment to `total` to the beginning of the month loop to avoid repeating it.

```
for x in range(12):
    total = 0
    for y in range(30):
        r = f.readline()
        total += int(r)
    avg = total/30
    print(avg)
```